# How can I reduce voltage for my Arduino?

Tags: arduino, voltage, sensor, signal, servo

I would like to use a muscle signal sensor for controlling the servo motors and LEDS through my Arduino. I would like to reduce the voltage from 18V to 9V on the signal wire (green wire on the picture) The wiring between the sensor and the Arduino on the picture might not be correct, as I still haven't tried it.

The Arduino is the Nano model with 7V - 12V input and 5V operating.

The servo specifications:

- Model: GS-1502
- Operating Voltage: 3.3V - 6V
- No Load Current: 100mA (at 6V)
- Loading Current: 450mA (at 6V)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Depending on which Arduino you have, it might accept some voltage directly. Which Arduino you have and what does the documentaton or manual say about it?

Comment: Resistor, Zener diode. To my knowledge most of the various Arduinos can accept power supplies higher than 5V but not I/Os higher than 5V (or 3.3V on some)

Comment: Please add a datasheet link for the sensor module. It's probably not a good idea to power the servos from the Arduino 5 V regulator. It's probably not rated for that much current.

Comment: You are connecting -Vss from the sensor to one GND pin on the Arduino, and a GND pin on the sensor to another GND pin. These are probably connected together which will short the negative 9V battery.

Comment: why did you include information about the servo in your post? ... the servos are irrelevant to the question ... your question is about the sensor output, yet there is no info about the sensor

Comment: Just to make sure you know to avoid disappointment: good EMG requires good electrodes and good skin prep. You need fresh electrodes, short shielded cables, and skin prep. Skip any of those and you'll be fighting gremlins. The best place for that EMG amplifier is right next to the electrodes, with rather short wires. It will work farther away, but the farther it is, the more problematic it gets. The reference electrode (black wire) is quite important for low artifacts: abrade that skin some, have alcohol handy, read up on electrophysiology skin prep.

Comment: Ideal results for hobby EMG are obtained with active differential electrodes - basically a little "bar" that has two gold-plated spring-loaded electrodes sticking out, and a cable with conditioned signal coming out. Those were available as far back as early 1980s as off-the-shelf products.

Answer (score 3):

- Do **not** power the servos from the Arduino.  They can draw an ampere or more, and the voltage regulator on the Arduino is only rated for a few hundred milliamperes (a fraction of an ampere.)
- Do not power servos from 9V batteries.  They are not intended for high current.  They will not last long when the servos move.
- The [Arduino Nano](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/ArduinoNanoManual23.pdf) uses a [UA78M05CDCYRG3](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ua78m.pdf) 5V regulator.  It can accept up to 35V input.  You can power the Nano from 9V, no problem.
- You appear to be using [this EMG sensor.](https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Sensors/Biometric/Muscle%20Sensor%20v3%20Users%20Manual.pdf)  Most of the examples show it connected directly to the Arduino, even when powered from two 9V batteries.  If you feel a need to protect the Nano's ADC input, use a voltage divider made of two 1k resistors.

Voltage divider:

[image]

---

The output from the EMG will be at most 9V.  It has a bipolar signal (ranges between -9V and +9) inside, but there's a rectifier on the board that gives you the absolute value of the EMG signal.

Comment: Instead of "They are not intended for high current" I'd say they *can't provide* high current. It doesn't matter what they're *intended for*. Maybe you wrote that because you are subconsciously making the same mistake yourself!

Comment: I know quite well what a 9V transistor battery is capable of.  They are intended for low current use.  They will in fact provide an ampere or so for a very short time.

Comment: If, as you say, they *can* do it, then why does it matter what they're intended for?

Comment: Because it won't do it long enough to be useful.

Comment: then I suggest editing the answer to say that. Nothing about "intended for"...